# Why won't C++ let me use a string as a data member in a class?

Tags: c++, string, class, stl

So I have the following code in a header file named Classes.h:

```
#ifndef CLASSESS_H
#define CLASSESS_H

class PalindromeCheck
{
private:
    string strToCheck;
    string copy;

public:
    PalindromeCheck(string testSubject) : strToCheck(testSubject) {} //Constructor

    void Check()
    {
        copy = strToCheck; //Copy strToCheck into copy so that once strToCheck has been reversed, it has something to be checked against.
        reverse(strToCheck.begin(), strToCheck.end());  //Reverse the string so that it can be checked to see if it is a palindrome.

        if (strToCheck == copy) 
        {
            cout << "The string is a palindrome" << endl;
            return;
        }
        else 
        {
            cout << "The string is not a palindrome" << endl;
            return;
        }
    }
};

#endif
```

And now I have the following code in a source file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include "Classes.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    PalindromeCheck firstCheck("ATOYOTA");

    firstCheck.Check();

    return 0;
}
```

When I compiled this code using the Visual C++ Compiler, I got a ton of errors messages that all stemmed from these first four:

'strToCheck': unknown override specifier
missing type specifier - int assumed.
'copy': unknown override specifier
missing type specifier - int assumed.

I tried adding in `#include <string>` into the header file and recompiled it but it did absolutely nothing.  This confuses me because I thought I could use a string as a datatype, but apparently not in a class?  It would be great if someone could help me out because I don't know why my code isn't working.

Comment: Get rid of `using namespace std` and replace `string` with `std::string` and your problems (including the ones you didn't realize you had) will go away.

Comment: The `using namespace std;` comes after `#include "Classes.h"`. Thus, when defining `class PalindromCheck` the compiler tries to find `string` in the global namespace but it cannot be found. (Not yet.) Solution is provided in answer...

Answer (score 7):

You need to `#include <string>` in the class header itself.

You also need to either use the `std::` namespace (preferable) or also add `using namespace std` to that header as well ([which I strongly discourage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)).

Comment: So post your latest code in your question, not some old version. Otherwise, of course people will point out the obvious problems, which you've apparently since fixed. And that's a waste of everyone's time.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!  I didn't see the last part of your answer until after I posted that comment, so I deleted it.  My code works now! Thanks!